# Shir Shel Yom and Daily Tehillim

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms

A thought occurred to me: for those who read Tehillim according to a monthly schedule, are there any rules/regulations regarding or prohibitions against or problems with reading the same chapter twice in a day, aside from those that are meant to be said more than once, such as Ashrei (ch145 + extra verses)?  So, for instance, if it is a Wednesday and it is the 19th of the month, does one say ch.94 as part of Shacharit or when reading the chapters for the 19th of the month (ch.90-96) or both during Shacaharit and during the time one sets aside for Tehillim reading?

Comment: Why would you think it's a problem?

Comment: +1. I've often wondered about a ~subset of this question, viz "Can someone who says _T'hilim_ according to a weekly/monthly schedule count psalms found in prayers against that quota?". (I assumed he'd say 94 as part of _shacharis_ but wondered whether he'd need to repeat it.)

Comment: Oh, wait, I just realized that's not what you're asking at all. You're asking whether he **may** repeat it. In that case, I second @Scimonster's comment: why shouldn't he?

Comment: I suppose I was thinking along the lines of not repeating a certain bracha, part of a particular service etc (such as the Shema) more than the required number of times a day, once one is yotzei. But perhaps this does not apply to the tehillim at all as there is no requirement to read the tehillim according to the monthly order?

Comment: You can say as much Tehillim as you want whenever you want.

Comment: @msh210 If he's taken this regimen upon himself as a requirement, maybe אין עושין מצות חבילות חבילות would be a factor in your question?

Comment: @Fred, good point. Maybe I should [ask](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3):

The Psalm of the day is said as part of davening and is unconnected to any recitation of Tehillim that you may decide to do otherwise.

There are other Tehillim besides Ashrei that are repeated, BTW. The Sunday Psalm of the day (number 24) may be recited up to 3 times in the same day if that Sunday is a fast day. Granted, that's part of davening.

AFAIK, any Tehillim may be said as often as you wish.

Comment: Or if it's the second day of Rosh Hashannah. If so, many say it at ma'ariv, while returning the Torah, and during shsh"y